# Two networks with same subnet

Tags: networking, router, routing, network-interface

I have a MikroTik routerboard that I want to configure with two networks. One that connects my routerboard to the internet, and the other one that makes me able to access the IP `192.168.1.1` on that network.

Currently, "*interface_1*" is the one that connects to the internet. The routerboard is configured to route all the `0.0.0.0/24` traffic to gateway `192.168.1.1`. I've also added the 192.168.1.0/24 range on the *interface_1*. 
[image: Routing on routerboard]

Now that's all working, I can access the network on *interface_1* just fine and I can access the internet. Now my question, how can I set the other network up so I can access `192.168.1.1` on *interface_2*?
I don't care if I need to connect to a fake IP that redirects al the traffic to 192.168.1.1 on *interface_2*, I just need to be able to access `192.168.1.1` without the router thinking that I want to acces `192.168.1.1` on *interface_1*.

[image: Drawing of network]

Disclaimer; I'm fairly new to networking and such. I did search for a solution, but I can't find it

Comment: Routers route between networks, not from a network to the same network, so you need different networks on router interfaces. A bridge, e.g. switch, will connect the same network on different interfaces, but bridges don't route. How, for instance, would a router know to which of the interfaces with the same network packets from the `192.168.88.0/24` a packet should be sent?

Comment: To follow up on what @RonMaupin said.  If I told you to go to 123 Main St, and there were two Main St's in town, would not know how to get there....